# Can i give a file a unique id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, file

Im working with nodejs.

I have a webpage that accepts an excel upload, reads the excel and creates products based on the excels info read. My reading algorithm only works with certain format, the excel cant be written in just any random way. So i offer an excel file written in that format for the user to download, fill it (it only allows certain cells to be modified) and then upload it.

The problem is distinguishing the right file (the one i offer), from any other random file without wasting time reading it. Is there any way to give a file an id or something that certifies that it is actually the file that is suppossed to be uploaded? At first i thought about the name, but anyone can upload a random file with the same name so i dont see any way. Can you help me? Thank you

Comment: There is no way to do that, you will have to validate the format of the csv to see if it's actually valid

Comment: @Lk77 - note that CSV and Excel are not synonymous. One can create custom properties for an Excel file. Whether that is a good idea is another question....